Facebook custom label POST request works but I'm getting an error in return
I'm using Python to create a script that allows me to create a label in the inbox (for a Facebook page), and then associate or tag a user with a specific label.
This is the function I made:
def associate_label_to_user(recipient_id, label_id, access_token):
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{label_id}/label?access_token={access_token}"
data = {
    "user": recipient_id
}

response = requests.post(url, json=data)
response_json = response.json()
# print(response_json)

if response.status_code == 200:
    success = response_json['success']
    if success:
        print("[LOGS] Association of label to user successful")
else:
    print("[LOGS] Error associating label to a user")

I'm reading their documents here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/custom-labels/, and I'm not experiencing any other problem.
Whenever I run the script, it works (I see the user being labeled correctly), but I'm getting this error in return:
{'error': {'message': 'Unsupported request - method type: post', 'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'ApHRHoVZFM_BUqHpOs3KdKX'}}

I don't understand what this means, when it works for me anyway.
